# Create ifstream with user generated filename?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I'm having a problem creating a `ifstream` with a filename which isn't defined at compile time. The following example works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string file, word;
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> file;
    ifstream in("thisFile.cpp");
    while(in >> word)
        count++;
    cout << "That file has " << count << " whitespace delimited words." << endl;

}
```

But if I change the line `ifstream in("thisFile.cpp");` to `ifstream in(file);` I get a compile error. Why is this?

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses. c_str() did the trick. I think I'm going to pick James' answer because it has the most detail.
edit: I guess James figured he already had enough rep and removed his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File streams in C++98 only take C-style character strings for the constructor argument, not C++ strings, an oversight in the C++98 standard that was corrected in the C++11 update. If your compiler doesn't support C++11 yet, you can open a file from a string name by simply calling `c_str()` to get a C-style character pointer out of a C++ string:

```
ifstream in(file.c_str());
```

Answer (score 3):

before c++11 the ifstream constructor only took a  `const char*` not a string for the filename.

So try `ifstream in(file.c_str());` instead

Comment: +1 Beat me by 10 seconds, and mentioned the difference between C++03 and C++11.

Comment: Expecting lots of identical answers to this one :)

Answer (score 2):

You need the [c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method:

```
ifstream in(file.c_str());
```